# rich:editor ruins html?

Tags: jsf, tinymce, richfaces

Strange behaviour. I use rich:editor with these attributes: (Irrelevant data removed)

```
    HtmlEditor editor = new HtmlEditor();
    editor.setValueExpression("value", ve);
    editor.setTheme("advanced");
    editor.setValueExpression("viewMode", viewModeValueExpression);
            panel.getChildren().add(editor);
```

Now my problem is that whenever I load a ready-made html text such as this (In source mode):

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Done</title>
</head>
<body style="direction: ltr; font-size: medium; color: #0000FF;">
    <p>When the menu loads, navigate to and open Image Editor.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Change to VisualMode and then back to SourceMode, I see that the editor removed all of my html data and now the source mode is this:

```
<p>When the menu loads, navigate to and open Chul Muzal.</p>
```

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE normally only edits a HTML fragment (the bit between the body tags) rather than a full page.  If however, you load the "fullpage" plugin ( http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/fullpage ) it will then edit the full page and also give the option to have a dialog box for editing properties like page title etc.

Regards,

Adrian Sutton
http://tinymce.ephox.com